# Why does Pywinauto always find many windows, even if it exactly exist only one window?

Tags: python, pywinauto

```
from pywinauto import application

app=application.Application()
app.connect(title_re = "| Zero Hedge", found_index = 0)

app.window_().SetFocus()
app.window_().TypeKeys('{F6}')
```

I have two main question:

1. What does found_index exactly control? Because every time I change the value of it, it turn out different result. And how can I decide the value of it to make sure I gain what I want, the window containing "| Zero Hedge"?
2. The code sometimes raises WindowAmbiguousError without found_index or with many different value of found_index. But I am pretty sure that I only have one tab whose title contains "| Zero Hedge". Why it always detect many windows? How can I fix it?

Thank you for all your help. :)

Comment: I don't know about `found_index`, and I can't find it in the documentation. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, it's a new argument introduced in [pywinauto 0.5.3](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/releases/tag/0.5.3). See the docs for [find_windows](http://pywinauto.github.io/docs/code/pywinauto.findwindows.html?highlight=find_windows#pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows).

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding `top_level_only=True` in the `connect` call (`found_index=0` can be removed). Method `connect` only connects to the application process in some sense (process is found using window title, not necessary top-level window). But the process contains only one top level window (`app.window_()` is searching top level window by default while `connect` is not).

Another option to avoid ambiguity:

```
Application().connect(title='your title', class_name='Chrome_WidgetWin_1')
```

`found_index` is not the only way to eliminate ambiguity. I would say it's a last frontier when other criteria do not work.

EDIT: BTW, as Roel mentioned, `"a|b"` means `"a"` or `"b"`. So in your case `"| Zero Hedge"` means `"" (empty sting)` or `"Zero Hedge"`. There are many invisible top-level windows with empty caption. Please use `|` carefully.

Correct regex for any symbols is `.*`. The dot `.` means any symbol, while star `*` means any number of repetitions.

Your case should probably look so: `".*Zero Hedge"`.

Comment: `title_re`doesn't need to match the whole window title; it matches any part of the title. Therefore `title_re=""` even matches any possible title, not just windows with empty caption!

Answer (score 1):

You find multiple windows because you use a regular expression to match the window titles, and your regular expression happens to match any string. `| Zero Hedge` means match either `" Zero Hedge"` or the empty string.

To fix that, you need to escape the `|`:

```
app.connect(title_re = r"\| Zero Hedge")
```

Comment: In face, I have tried you suggestion before, but it raise WindowNotFoundError. However, thank you for your help!

Comment: @MarsLee: Note that you either have to use a double backslash (`"\\| Zero Hedge"`) or use a raw string (`r"\| Zero Hedge"`). Not saying you didn't think of that; just a possible reason why it didn't work.

Comment: I tried both suggestions and... they both raise WindowNotFoundError. This really makes me crazy...

Comment: Is it because I have two screens...?